# Error no match for 'operator[]'

Tags: c++

```
#define Nal 41
#define maxcar 61
#define opmax 51

typedef char nombre[maxcar];
typedef char sistema_operativo[opmax];


typedef struct
{
    nombre usuario;
    sistema_operativo opera;
    float memoria;
    bool usara_app;


}TFG;

typedef TFG FP[Nal];


 void introducir_inform(TFG FP, float &memoria, int &numuser)
    {
        numuser=0;
        char respapp, resp;
        cout<<"Desea introducir algun usuario s/n: ";
        cin >> resp;

        while(resp=='s' && numuser<Nal)
        {

            cout<<"Introduzca nombre y apellidos sin espacios blancos: ";
            cin >> FP[numuser].usuario;
            cout<<"Introduzca sistema operativo sin espacios blancos: ";
            cin >> FP.opera;
            cout<<"Introduzca memoria disponible: ";
            cin >> FP.memoria;
            cout<<"Esta dispuesto a usar la app S/N ";
            cin >> respapp;

            switch(respapp)
            {
            case 'S':
                FP.usara_app=true;
                break;

            case 'N':
                FP.usara_app=false;
                break;
            }
            numuser++;
        }
    }
```

Porque aparece:

> ```
> error: no match for 'operator[]' in 'FP[numuser]'
> ```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la definición del tipo `TFG`?

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <conio2.h>

using namespace std;

#define Nal 41
#define maxcar 61
#define opmax 51

typedef char nombre[maxcar];
typedef char sistema_operativo[opmax];


typedef struct
{
 nombre usuario;
 sistema_operativo opera;
 float memoria;
 bool usara_app;


}TFG;

typedef TFG FP[Nal];

Comment: es una struct...

Comment: Me parece muy bien que sea una `struct`. Me parece muy mal que no la añadas a la pregunta editando la misma.

Comment: Por que no deja usarla como un array??

Comment: Añade la estructura a la pregunta. Para hacerlo, pulsa el enlace "*editar*" al final de tu pregunta.

Comment: Ahi esta........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás usando los alias de tipo de manera incorrecta. Antes de C++11 los alias de tipo tenían el formato:

```
typedef tipo alias;
```

De manera que podías hacer que el tipo de datos `tipo` recibiese el alias `alias`:

```
typedef int Entero;
```

En la línea anterior, el tipo `Entero` es el mismo que el tipo `int` porque `Entero` es un alias de `int`<sup>1</sup>.

---

Por lo tanto, estos alias de tipos

```
typedef char nombre[maxcar];
typedef char sistema_operativo[opmax];
```

Están diciendo que el tipo `char` puede ser referido como `nombre[maxcar]` o como el tipo `sistema_operativo[opmax]`, lo cuál no tiene ni pies ni cabeza. Parece que estás confundiendo alias de tipos con instancias de tipos, posiblemente querías hacer esto:

```
char nombre[maxcar];
char sistema_operativo[opmax];
```

Lo mismo te ha sucedido en el alias `TFG`, seguramente querías hacer esto:

```
TFG FP[Nal];
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Se considera confusa esta definición de alias de tipos, por lo que a partir de C++11 se usa el formato:

```
using alias = tipo;
```

Aunque el formato de alias anterior se puede seguir usando.

Comment: Entonces como lo uso en un array?

Comment: Tu problema es que no creabas un array, creabas un alias. Si lo declaras como `TFG FP[Nal];` entonces es un array y puede usarse como tal.