# ¿Como hago para que la nota final sea diferente para cada alumno?

Tags: c++, struct

Tengo un modulo que recibe el nombre del alumno su participación y las notas, su nota final es una operación con todas las notas, vale, pero al introducir mas de dos alumnos la nota del primero se repite con la del segundo, ¿Como puedo arreglar eso?

```
    void listado_notas(const CUM FP, int numest)
{
    system("cls");
    float notafinal = 0;
    cout << "\n Listado de alumnos\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < numest; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nalumno: " << FP[i].alnom;
        if (FP[i].presentado == 'S' && FP[i].entrega == 'S')
        {
            cout << "\nnota del test: " << FP[i].nota[0];
            cout << "\nnota del ex. problemas: " << FP[i].nota[1];
            cout << "\nnota de practica: " << FP[i].nota[2];
            cout << "\nnota de SMC: " << FP[i].nota[3];
            cout << "\nha estudiado ";
            switch (FP[i].part)
            {
            case 'M':
                cout << "Mucho";
                break;

            case 'P':
                cout << "Poco";
                break;

            case 'N':
                cout << "Nada";
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nNo presentado";
        }

        notafinal = 0.2 * (FP[i].nota[2]) + 0.3 * (FP[i].nota[3]) + 0.5 * (0.3 * (FP[i].nota[0]) + 0.7 * (FP[i].nota[1]));

        if (notafinal >= 4.5 && notafinal < 5)
        {
            notafinal = 5;
        }
        cout << "\nnota final: " << notafinal << endl;
    }
}
```

La nota final debería estar bien? Ella debería ser diferente para cada alumno, no se bien como arreglarla...

Comment: ¿Cuál es la definición del tipo `CUM`?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, es `typedef notas CUM[N];`,  `notas` es un typedef struct.

Comment: Y la nota final quería usar fuera del struct.

Comment: Es mentira. Esa no es la definición de `CUM`, porque de serlo, tu programa no compila tal y como ya se te dijo en dos ocasiones anteriormente ([aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/321916/error-no-match-for-operator) y [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/322260/ning%c3%ban-operador-no-coincide)) también se te ha dicho anteriormente que si tienes código que compartir en una pregunta, debes hacerlo [editando la pregunta no haciendo un comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/321916/error-no-match-for-operator#comment583896_321916).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar a poner el `float notafinal = 0;` dentro del bucle for. Así obligas a que cada vez que se revise la información del alumno, la nota final se reinicie y se vuelva a calcular para cada uno.

Otra opción es añadir un atributo a tu estructura `CUM` que sea la nota final, así las tendrías bien guardadas.

Comment: Era eso, gracias @Luis.

Comment: ¡De nada! Un placer ayudar